# How to parse ANTRL Syntax Tree to feed Custom objects using Visitors

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

I am currently facing this problem :
I am using ANTLR to parse a terraform file using the grammar provided by ANTLR and would like to create custom objects for each branch of the Syntax tree.
For example :
[image]

I would like to take the subTree provider and make an object TerraformProvider Containing the following properties :

- provider_name : string
- A dictionnary containing the values (region -> us-east-1 ) for example

For such purpuse i created a  TerraformVisitor class :

```
using Antlr4.Runtime.Misc;
using ANTLRch1.tmptest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ANTLRch1.terraformObjects;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;

namespace ANTLRch1
{
    public class TerraformVisitor: terraformBaseVisitor<string>
    {

        public List<TerraformProvider> Providers = new List<TerraformProvider>();

        public override string VisitChildren([NotNull] IRuleNode node)
        {
            props.Add(node.GetText(), node.GetText()); 
            return base.VisitChildren(node);
        }

        public override string VisitProvider([NotNull] terraformParser.ProviderContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            string value = context.PROVIDER().GetText();
            props.Add(id, value);
            var x = base.VisitChildren(context);
            Console.WriteLine(props);
            return base.VisitProvider(context);
        }

        public override string VisitResource([NotNull] terraformParser.ResourceContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            return base.VisitResource(context);
        }

        public override string VisitVariable([NotNull] terraformParser.VariableContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            string value = context.VARIABLE().GetText();
            return base.VisitVariable(context);
        }

        public override string VisitFile_([NotNull] terraformParser.File_Context context)
        {
            return base.VisitFile_(context);
        }

        public override string VisitBlockbody([NotNull] terraformParser.BlockbodyContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            return base.VisitBlockbody(context);
        }

        public override string VisitArgument([NotNull] terraformParser.ArgumentContext context)
        {
            var c = context.GetType();
            string id = context.GetText();
            return base.VisitArgument(context);
        }

        public override string VisitIdentifier([NotNull] terraformParser.IdentifierContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            return base.VisitIdentifier(context);
        }

        public override string VisitVal([NotNull] terraformParser.ValContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            return base.VisitVal(context);
        }

        public override string VisitResourcetype([NotNull] terraformParser.ResourcetypeContext context)
        {
            string id = context.GetText();
            return base.VisitResourcetype(context);
        }



    }
}
```

But i am not sure how to handle the creation of the objects since for example a variable have element in common with provider etc ..

I would greatly appreciate your help
Thank you

Comment: I would probably just subclass the visitor class from `terraformBaseVisitor<TerraformProvider>` then at each visitor, something like `return new TerraformProvider() { provider_name = ...., .... };`, since you want to return a `TerraformProvider` for each rule. Note, for some rules, you will want to return the result from calling `Visit(child)` and not a `new TerraformProvider()`. Do not call `base.Visit.....()` since you want to call your visitor class methods per child, not the default visitor on the child. You will also need to override each and every Visit...() method in TerraformVisitor.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of which type of object you're currently creating, but then you'd need to check the type and conditionally process each node.

One idea would be to use multiple visitors.  You don't have to use the same visitor for all of your tree processing.

For your example, perhaps you create a `TerraformVisitor` that handles the high level constructs, and then you could have (using your example) a `ProviderVisitor` that handles children of a Provider node, and a `VariableVisitor` that handles children of a Variable node.

This approach will keep the clutter down, and allow you to handle different contexts with different visitors.

NOTE:  This works for visitors since you are in control of what children to visit as well as what visitor to use to visit them.  For Listeners, the entire tree will be walked with the Listener (You can walk a subtree with a Listener, but it will walk the entire subtree)